# VBA, PowerPoint Freezing

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new inVBA and I need your help.
I code in VBA project inside PowerPoint instance.
I programed userRibbon to do somethig and it works well.
Now I added one functionality. Its task is to get name of user (login of PC account) and write this to the slide in powerPoint. There is different between who is speaker and who is creator of PowerPoint presentation. Therefore normal inputbox is not optimal for this solution. I added new form to my project and I designed it. Two textBoxes and two Buttons,  OK and Cancel.

Now, By VBA.Interaction.Environ$("username") I get the username. 
By this name I am setting both textBoxes then I want to show myform waiting for confirmation. This is a point where Powerpoint absolutely freez and thats my problem. No Errors, nothing. It is necesery to call Task Manager and the powerpoint presentation switch off.  If I set breakpoint at beginig of procedure and start to step the code the procedure finish well without freezing. I do not know why! Please do you help me?

```
private speaker as String
private creator as String

Sub GetUserName()
  Dim strDisplayName As String
  Dim objUser As Variant

  objUser = VBA.Interaction.Environ$("username")    ' return username

  'open DB 
   Call OpenDatabase

   'load data from DB, I want name, not usernam
   rst.Open"SELECT name FROM tbl_User WHERE login = '" & objUser & "' ;", ..........

   if rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
      strDisplayName = rst(0)
   else
      .....
   end if

   'close DB
   Call Closedatabse

   myInputBox.TextBox1.Text = strDisplayName     'fill first textBox
   myInputBox.TextBox2.Text = strDisplayName     'fill second textBox
   myInputBox.Show   <= point of freezing    
                                                                                                         
   Call WriteUserNames(speaker, creator)              ' write name into the slide

End Sub
```

Comment: In a situation like that, I put a temporary MsgBox "Ran" statement near the top. I rerun the code, moving the statement down a line each time until it no longer appears. When it stops showing, it's usually the line before MsgBox causing the problem.

Comment: Hello, I am not shure if I understood well. Could you give me some example. Thank You